# Exercicio While para Prova

Tags: python, while

Não consigo fazer esse exercício, nem com while e nem com for. Se vocês poderem me disponibilizar a maneira de como se faz com While e For, ficarei grato.

> 3. Dada uma lista de números, diga qual o maior número da lista. Utilize a função len( ) para descobrir o tamanho da lista e a estrutura de repetição while ​para percorrer a lista.

Lembrando que o programa deve ser feito exatamente como é pedido no exercício.

Código que consegui fazer, porém super errado:

```
lista = [0, 10, 20, 50, 80]
maior = lista[0]

while maior in lista < maior:
    print(maior)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bem, não vou entrar no mérito do quanto você deve ter se esforçado ou não pra fazer isto.

Basicamente, você precisa percorrer todos os elementos da lista e verificar qual é o maior. Isso pode ser feito de diversas maneiras.

O que eu fiz no meu código foi fazer com que a variável `i` recebesse a cada laço um índice válido (de `lista`), isto é, ele inicia em **0** e vai até `len(lista) - 1`. E então verificar se o elemento neste índice é maior do que o maior salvo até agora (na variável `maior`)

```
lista = [0, 10, 20, 50, 80]

maior = lista[0]
i = 0
while i < len(lista):
    if lista[i] > maior:
        maior = lista[i]
    i += 1

print('O maior é {}'.format(maior))
```

[Veja funcionando no repl.it.](https://repl.it/IPhS)

É possível fazer isso sem usar nenhum *loop*, com a função `max()`

```
maior = max(lista)
```

Comment: Funcionou, mas porque o if ficou desse jeito? E na mesma linha do maior = lista[i]?

Comment: Isso é um ternário. Funciona assim, se a condição for atendida (`maior < lista[i]`), a variável `maior` recebe o valor `lista[i]` senão, ela recebe o valor `maior` (ela mesma, no caso).

Comment: Alterei pra ficar mais claro, @Pigot

Comment: Tem alguma maneira de fazer sem ser por ternário? Editei meu código acima, ele só printa o último, e nao o maior ( o que eu editei)

Comment: Acabei de mudar pra um if normal

Comment: Que código, @Pigot?

Comment: Deu certo, muito obrigado! :)

Comment: Um detalhe: é bom que você inicie `maior` com o primeiro item da lista, pois se a lista possuir apenas números negativos, o zero continuará sendo o maior - e pode nem existir um zero na lista.

Comment: Valeu, @AndersonCarlosWoss

Comment: Faz sentido, haha, obrigado!